# Doesn't NHibernate HQL support "with" keyword?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, hql

I'm trying to build a HQL that can left join values from a collection, in order to give me the chance of checking "is null" on it.

Taken from the example from hibernate manual:

```
from Cat as cat
    left join cat.kittens as kitten
        with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
```

doesn't seem to work in NHibernate, since it doesn't recognize the "with" keyword. How else are you supposed to left join and check for no-matching entries if you cannot specify join-clauses directly in your join as opposed to in your WHERE-statement?

I'm running NHibernate 2.0.0.

Comment: They seem to have implemented it in NH 2.1, however with some quirks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported in NHibernate.  It was [first requested in 2005](http://jira.nhibernate.org/browse/NH-514) and is by far the most popular requested feature.

Comment: You don't happen to have any suggestion on a workaround, or if it can be achieved using a Criteria in some way?

Comment: I've voted for that suggestion as well, a while ago ...  Hope that once upon a time, they implement it

Answer (score 1):

I think you can workaround it by using an outer join, and then do this:

```
from Cat c
left join c.Kittens as kitten
where kitten.bodyweight > 10 or kitten.bodyweight is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently they're working on it ...
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-514

I've received an update report from the NHibernate JIRA yesterday, and this issue should be fixed in NHibernate v2.1.0 Alpha 3 :)